# Save navigation property as null

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a `Job` model and `StatusOnHold` model. 
I added navigation property `StatusOnHold` in the `Job` model.
from some reason, when I'm saving the `Job` model with an empty `StatusOnHold`, I'm still getting value in the `StatusOnHoldId` in the `Job` model.

1. when `StatusOnHold` is empty, I'm trying to receive *NULL* value in the `StatusOnHoldId` in the `Job` model.
2. when `StatusOnHold` is not empty, I'm trying to get `StatusOnHoldId` and save the value in the `StatusOnHold` model (which it's working like that now).

Thank you so much.

Here is my Models...

```
public class StatusOnHoldViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}

public class JobViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string JobNote { get; set; }
    public JobStatus JobStatus { get; set; }
    public CompanyViewModel Company { get; set; }
    public CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }

    public StatusOnHoldViewModel StatusOnHold { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Controller...

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(JobViewModel jobViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var job = _mapper.Map<Job>(jobViewModel);
            var newjobId = await _jobRepository.AddAsync(job);

            return RedirectToAction("details", new { id = newjobId });
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And here is the view...

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="m-1">On-Hold</div>
        <textarea asp-for="StatusOnHold.Note" style="height:86px; min-height:86px" class="form-control" placeholder="Reason..."></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="StatusOnHold.Note" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I'm still getting value in the StatusOnHoldId in the Job model.`what value do you get in database?

Comment: In the Database, I'm getting, StatusOnHoldId same as the Id in the StatusOnHold (which is make sense). But I'm trying to pass *NULL*. for both StatusOnHoldId in the Job and Id in the StatusOnHold

Answer (score 0):

You don't have property for the *StatusOnHoldViewModel* the navigation property alone will not work.

So add

```
public int StatusOnHoldViewModelId { get; set; }
```

to your *JobViewModel*

Comment: I tried to add it like this `public int? StatusOnHoldViewModelId { get; set; }` but it didnt work.

Comment: Then I think you need to use the _ForeignKeyAttribute_ like _[ForeignKey("StatusOnHoldViewModel")]_. I didn't check, so maybe I'm wrong. Please look at the docs.

Comment: By the way, why do you name these classes ViewModel? View Models normally are for presentation and not for the business layer. They serve the UI (the view) with data

Comment: I just tried to add the ForeignKeyAttribute but it didn't let me. It's says "property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'Job'".

Comment: I guess the problem is... when i pass the information from the View to the Controller, I'm getting StatusOnHold.Id=0 even tho I'm not sending any values (on the StatusOnHold)

Answer (score 0):

StatusOnHoldId  will not be empty and it always have data, if you do not write note in textarea, it  will look like `{ "id":0,"note":null}` on action for jobViewModel` ,this wll create a new record.

A workaround is that you could set `StatusOnHold` as null when `note` is null:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(JobViewModel jobViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(jobViewModel.StatusOnHold.Note == null)
        {
            jobViewModel.StatusOnHold = null;
        }

        var job = _mapper.Map<Job>(jobViewModel);
        var newjobId = await _jobRepository.AddAsync(job);

        return RedirectToAction("details", new { id = newjobId });
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for taking long time. It did solve most of the problem and I **thank you** for that. But, what if I have more properties and not only `Note`? (I have multiple properties in the `StatusOnHold`). and Thank you again

Comment: @Noah You could use `||` to append other properties to `jobViewModel.StatusOnHold.Note == null`.Or you could have a look at [automapper conditional mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html)